# Connect to hardware component in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kiosk, hardware-interface

So, I have an ASP.NET 5 application that uses MVC 6, and I want to connect and use a hardware component, a 6100 Check reader from Pertech Industries, and what I am given right now is a bunch of .dll files and c# model classes. How would I use the .dll files to let my application recognize this device and perform the api functions on it?

I have never worked with hardware components like this before so I am currently quite lost and would appreciate any help. Thank you for your time!

Comment: so they have .net dll api support? using a website doesn't make sense. Your website is html and javascript when it ends up on the client. You're going to need another '.Net' client

Comment: @ChrisHayes I'm not sure what you mean. They are .dll files that work with a c# example project they have, but it is not a .net project. Is it not possible to do something like this with a .net web app? I'm new to this so this is quite confusing, sorry.

Comment: what is their example project? Windows forms, Console App?

Comment: if it's not a .Net app then the dll's are not going to help. Maybe if they are 'COM' dlls but even then that's a huge leap for someone new to this.

Comment: It seems like a c# windows app, it's really old, made with visual studio 2008. How can I tell what kind of .dll it is? and how would you think I should go about approaching this?

Comment: you should be able to open a visual studio 2008 project with the current version of visual studio. If so, first steps, see if you can build the project. If so, try running it and then start examining it. Else, try reading the code and see what they are doing. Other than that, try adding the dlls to a current project (probably NOT an MVC app, try a winform app just to play around with the dlls) and examine the classes and how they work.

Comment: Wait so you're saying this will not work with an MVC app? because my all is using MVC 6. I can look at the source, all it is is just DLL files and model files and then the main page for it. It's not .net or anything that would help me. Also it doesn't build.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105993/discussion-between-chris-hayes-and-alfred-shaker).